# How to use result of a function that uses promises

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise, es6-promise

I have a function,

```
  asdf() {
    var a = fooController.getOrCreateFooByBar(param);
    console.log("tryna do thing");
    console.log(a); //undefined
    if (!a.property) {
      //blah
    }
```

that dies. getOrCreateFooByBar does a

```
  Model.find({phoneNumber : number}).exec()
  .then(function(users) {})
```

and finds or creates the model, returning it at the end:

```
.then(function(foo) { return foo}
```

How can I use the result of this in `asdf()`? I feel like this is a fairly easy question but I am getting stuck. If I try to do a.exec() or a.then() I get 'a cannot read property of undefined' error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea about Promises (as opposed to passed callbacks) is that they are actual objects you can pass around and return.

`fooController.getOrCreateFooByBar` would need to return the Promise it gets from `Model.find()` (after all of the processing done on it). Then, you'll be able to access it in `a` in your `asdf` function.

In turn, `asdf()` should *also* return a Promise, which would make `asdf()` thenable as well. As long as you keep returning Promises from asynchronous functions, you can keep chaining them.

```
// mock, you should use the real one
const Model = { find() { return Promise.resolve('foo'); } }; 

function badExample() {
  Model.find().then(value => doStuff(value));
}

function goodExample() {
  return Model.find().then(value => doStuff(value));
}

function asdf() {
  var a = badExample();
  var b = goodExample();

  // a.then(whatever); // error, a is undefined because badExample doesn't return anything

  return b.then(whatever); // works, and asdf can be chained because it returns a promise!
}

asdf().then(valueAfterWhatever => doStuff(valueAfterWhatever));
```

Comment: ah, this makes sense. I was not doing `return Model.find({...` Thanks!